# Configuring Eclipse for using with MSYS2

Tags: eclipse, mingw-w64, msys2

My I use Eclipse Mars and MSYS2. Eclipse does not recognize my MSYS2 installation. It contains Mingw-w64 for 32 bit compilation. Things I have found on the Internet did not work. What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Well, a bit late to the party, but it looks like there is *nothing special* about MSYS2: the usual procedure of setting up Eclipse to work with MinGW-w64 installation worked for me just fine.

The main issue is that as described in [Eclipse CDT FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_installed_MinGW_toolchain_on_my_PC_but_Eclipse_won.27t_find_it.) to detect MinGW toolchain CDT tries to find `mingw32-gcc.exe` in `PATH`, while MinGW-w64 have only `gcc` and `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` in its `bin` directory, so just adding MinGW-w64 `bin` directory to `PATH` won't work:

> Despite having g++.exe or gcc.exe on your PATH and having defined
>   MINGW_HOME, you may still get a “Toolchain "MinGW GCC" is not
>   detected” message (CDT 8.4 on Luna 4.4.0). Make sure that a file
>   called "mingw32-gcc.exe" exists in MINGW_HOME\bin.

As it mentioned further in Eclipse CDT FAQ, the easy fix would be to copy `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe` to `mingw32-gcc.exe`:

> If it doesn't exist
>   (which happens with MinGW-W64), copy a -gcc.exe file (e.g.
>   i686-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe) to mingw32-gcc.exe. If the dreaded message
>   still lingers around, reboot your system (don't just logout and
>   login).

After you did the copying described above, you can add MinGW-w64 `bin` directory to `PATH` and Eclipse will recognize the MinGW-w64 installation as MinGW toolchain. Since I don't like idea of polluting neither system nor user environment variables in Windows settings, I usually write a short batch file which adds MinGW-w64 `bin` directory to `PATH` and then starts Eclipse for me:

```
SET PATH=c:\msys32\mingw32\bin;%PATH%
START c:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

Even more later to the party - for me worked this solution: Right click project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment: set environment variable MINGW_HOME to C:/.../msys64/mingw64 click OK, and rest is automatically done by eclipse