# Install MinGW-w64 to work with Eclipse Mars

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw-w64, eclipse-mars

I have downloaded and installed MinGW-w64 for x86 machine, ut not changed the PATH variables.
I have Eclipse Mars CDT installed and working.

I want to use MinGW-w64 with Eclipse instead of old MinGW because the new 64-bit version accepts C++ 14. I was able to set lib and include libraries for one project, but got an error 'make' file in not found in PATH.'
How (step-by-step) should I proceed to install MinGW-w64 for all Eclipse projects? My machine is Win7 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: What do you mean by "ut not changed the PATH variables"? Also check the error message you mentioned ('make' file in not found in PATH'). Is this the *exact* message you got (I don't think so)? It might be better to copy and paste the exact error message you got.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33432546/153349